# Microsoft ISA Server - Filter - Conversion from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008 gives an error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com

We have a filter for Microsoft ISA Server 2006 written in C++. The code was originally compiled using Visual Studio 2005 and hunky dory. Since we are using Visual Studio 2008 for everything else, I tried to convert this project to Visual Studio 2008. The conversion wizard runs fine and the code compiles correctly.

However, when I try to deploy the output dll onto the server I get the following error

ISA Server failed to load Web Filter DLL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft ISA Server\".

To deploy

- I unregistered the original dll using regsvr32 \u
- Registered the new dll using regsvr32
- Start windows firewall service.

I suspect the error is because of Visual Studio 2008's handling of COM dlls. Has anybody seen this error before.

Cheers,
Hamid

-

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you need to deploy the new VS 2008 C runtime liberties.
[Here is the link to SP1 version (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

commands for install filter in ISA server

---

net  stop  fwsrv
  regsvr32.exec

### net start  fwsrv

commands for uninstall filter  from ISA server

---

net stop fwsrv
  regsvr32.exe /u /i 
  net start fwsrv